# Messing with Constraint CSS - width based on number of children

Tags: ccss

I'm using [gridstylesheets.org](http://gridstylesheets.org) to mess with Constraint CSS. My html is this:

```
<div class="box side-by-side">
  <div class="space"></div>
  <div class="space"></div>
  <div class="space"></div>
</div>
```

I would like each `.space` to be the height of the `.box` and to have evenly sized widths. In this case, the `.box` width divided by 3.

So far I have this:

```
.side-by-side .space {
  left: >= ::parent[left];
  top: >= ::parent[top];
  width: == 200;
  height: == 100;
}
.side-by-side {
  @h .space in([.side-by-side]);
}
```

It floats the `.space`s inside the parent but I'm not sure how to set the width. I would like to do something like this:

```
width: == ::parent[width] / ::parent[num-children];
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work:

```
(.space)[width] == ((.box)[width]) / 3;
```